# derivative $\frac{df(t)}{dt}$ of $f(t) = \int_0^t\ln{(s^2+t^2)} ds$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let $f(t) = \int_0^t \ln{(s^2+t^2)} ds$, how can I find the derivative $\frac{df(t)}{dt}$?

The function $\,\int_0^t \ln{(s^2+t^2)} ds$ is defined to be continuous in $s^2+t^2 > 0$ and $ s^2+t^2 \ne 0$, then by the Fundamental Theorem of Integral Calculus, we have $$ f´(t) = (\int_0^t \ln{(s^2+t^2)} ds)´= f(t) - f(0) = \ln{(s^2+t^2)} + \ln{(s^2)}$$

Is that correct? can I apply the same procedure to this function $g(t) = \int_0^t \frac{e^{st}}{s} ds$ ? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-orthodoxical approach.

Let $G(s,t)$ be a primitive of the integrand $g(s,t)$ (antiderivative on $s$): it is such that $\frac{\partial G}{\partial s}$ is the integrand.

The expression to be derived is thus $G(s,t)|_{s=0}^t=G(t,t)-G(0,t)$. When deriving with respect to $t$, we need to use the chain rule:
$$\frac{dG(t,t)}{dt}=\frac{\partial G}{\partial s}(t,t)\frac{dt}{dt}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}(t,t)\frac{dt}{dt}=g(t,t)+\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}(t,t),$$
$$\frac{G(0,t)}{dt}=\frac{\partial G}{\partial s}(0,t)\frac{d0}{dt}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}(0,t)\frac{dt}{dt}=\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}(0,t).$$
We are still missing the expression of $\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}$. $G(s,t)$ being a primitive (on $s$) of $g(s,t)$, $\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}(s,t)$ must be a primitive (on $s$) of $\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(s,t)$. So $$\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}(s,t)=\int \frac{2t}{s^2+t^2}ds=2\arctan\frac st+C.$$

Putting it all together, the answer is
$$g(t,t)+2\arctan1-2\arctan0=\ln(2t^2)+\frac{\pi}2$$

For the second case, $$\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}(s,t)=\int{e^{st}}ds=\frac{e^{st}}t+C.$$

and the answer,
$$\frac{e^{t^2}}t+\frac{e^{t^2}}t-\frac10.$$

Answer (score 2):

That is not correct. The integrand is itself a function of $t$. And clearly, the answer should be independent of $s$.

Check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Hence,
$$f'(t)=\ln(t^2+t^2)+\int_0^t \frac{2t}{s^2+t^2}\,ds=\ln(2t^2)+\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Similarly,
$$g'(t)=\frac{e^{t^2}}{t}+\int_0^t e^{st}\,ds=\frac{e^{t^2}}{t}+\frac{e^{t^2}-1}{t}=\frac{2e^{t^2}-1}{t}$$

Comment: Your last term should be $\pi/2$ since $s=t$ as you wrote it just before.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Oops, thanks! :P

Comment: Sorry for my dumbs questions but you integrate directly f ? or applied the Fundamental Theorem, really thanx for your patient ....

Comment: @Knight: I applied the Fundamental theorem of Calculus. Click the link I posted. And the integral is very common. What is the derivative of arctan(x)?

Comment: ok, really thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: using the [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement),

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}f(t)&=\ln{(s^2+t^2)}\bigg{|}_{s=t}\frac{d}{dt}(t)-\ln{(s^2+t^2)}\bigg{|}_{s=0}\frac{d}{dt}(0)+\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\ln{(s^2+t^2)}\,\mathrm{d}s
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

The integration can be carried out explicitly:

$$\,\int_0^t \ln{(s^2+t^2)} ds=(1/2)t(-4 + \pi + 2\ln 2 + 
      4\ln t)=:f(t)$$

So

$$f'(t)=\pi/2 + \ln(2t^2)$$

And $\int_0^t \frac{e^{st}}{s} ds$ does not converge (at $s= 0^+$).